# Material design list guideline Android 5.0

Tags: android, material-design

So I'm trying to follow googles new [Material Design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) on [lists](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-specs). But I can't quite get the results it seems like I should get. This is what it is supposed to look like:

[image: Google example of list with material design guidelines]

This is what my list looks like codewise:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/contact_item_image"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<View 
    android:id="@+id/middle_splitter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="72dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/right_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_item_prim_text"
        android:text="Test title"
        android:textSize="@dimen/subhead_txt_size"
        android:textColor="@color/blackish"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_item_sec_text"
        android:text="Test sec title"
        android:textSize="@dimen/body1_txt_size"
        android:textColor="@color/android_greyish"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Also tryed without LinearLayout:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/contact_item_image"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<View 
    android:id="@+id/middle_splitter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact_item_prim_text"
    android:text="Test title"
    android:textSize="@dimen/subhead_txt_size"
    android:textColor="@color/blackish"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="72dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/right_margin"
    android:layout_above="@id/middle_splitter"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact_item_sec_text"
    android:text="Test sec title"
    android:textSize="@dimen/body1_txt_size"
    android:textColor="@color/android_greyish"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="72dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/right_margin"
    android:layout_below="@id/middle_splitter"
    />
```

But the actual results is more like this:

[image: Device picture of personal list implementation]

I've basically just entered the dimensions directly as specified on the material design website but it doesn't look proper, am I misunderstanding these guidelines or something? The design itself could easely be made by just letting the LinearLayout handle it with weights or by using RelativeLayout positionening, I just though these guidelines were supposed to help us out... Any ideas on how we're supposed to use these guidelines or are they only for designers and not for developers?

**Edit**

So I put up an answer for a possible solution. Still think some code samples had been awesome from googles part.

Comment: Don't use paddingTop and paddingBottom with TextViews. Each font has some space above and below characters and TextView uses them. Just set gravity="center_vertical" and layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: @Zielony Ye I know, I just wanted to try to follow their guideline and see if I could get the right results. If you go to the website you'll see that they specify setting the padding for the given areas.

Comment: Just come across this exact issue, if we are not supposed to use the top and bottom padding, why are they included at all? The doc makes no sense regarding those two values

Comment: @DanielWilson Well I've come to the conclusion that the documentation is for designers and not for developers. In that sense the value is padding, but it is up to us developers how we want it implemented :)
For designers the documentation is great btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I end up going with this solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/contact_item_image"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/right_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contact_item_image"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_item_prim_text"
            android:text="Test title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/subhead_txt_size"
            android:textColor="@color/blackish"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_item_sec_text"
            android:text="Test sec title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/body1_txt_size"
            android:textColor="@color/android_greyish"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This gives me something that looks like this:

[image: new version of design]

Answer (score 1):

Use this **Pkmmte's** **[CircularImageView lib](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView)** in the imageview.

[image]